# Prevent unnecessary copying between large structs

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision

I have huge structs DataFrom and Data (which have different members in reality). Data is Created from DataFrom.

```
struct DataFrom{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
};
static DataFrom dataFrom;   
struct Data{
    int a;
    int b;
};    
class DataHandler{
    public:
        static Data getData(const DataFrom& data2){
            Data data;
            setA(data, data2);
            setB(data, data2);
            return data;
        }
    private:
        static void setA(Data& dest, const DataFrom& source){
            dest.a = source.a;
        }
        static void setB(Data& dest, const DataFrom& source){
            dest.b = source.b;
        }
};
int main(){
    auto data = DataHandler2::getData(dataFrom); // copy of whole Data structure
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

As Data is huge, in getData function, there is a copying of whole Data structure. Can this be prevented somehow in elegant way?

I had an idea about:

```
static void getData( Data& data, const DataFrom& data2);
```

But I would prefer to retrieve data as a return value, not an output parameter.

Comment: The compiler will normally optimize this so there's no copy necessary.

Comment: [No copying is actually taking place](https://godbolt.org/z/zPWP5j) in your example, being elided by NRVO.

Comment: You can `= delete` copy construction and assignment and only allow move semantics if you are scared of copies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I allow move construction and disallow assignment and copy construction of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472718/how-do-i-allow-move-construction-and-disallow-assignment-and-copy-construction-o)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It's not a dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two potential "copy hazards" to address here:

#### Copy hazard 1: The construction outside `getData()`

On the first line of  `main()`, where you commented "copy of whole Data structure" - as commenters noted, the structure won't actually be copied, due to the **Named Return Value Optimization**, or NRVO for short. You can read about it in this nice blog post from a few years back:

[Fluent{C++}: Return value optimizations](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/11/28/return-value-optimizations/)

In a nutshell: The compiler arranges it so that `data` inside the `getData` function, when it is called from `main()`, is actually an alias of `data` in main.

#### Copy hazard 2: `data` and `data2`

The second "copy scare" is with `setA()` and `setB()`. Here you must be more pro-active, since you do have two live, valid structs in the same function - `data` and `data2` within `getData()`. Indeed, if `Data` and `DataFrom` are simply large structs - then you will be doing a lot of copying from `data2` to `data`, the way you wrote your code.

**Move semantics to the rescue**

If, however, your `DataFrom` holds a reference to some allocated storage, say, `std::vector<int> a` instead of `int[10000] a` - you could *move* from your `DataFrom` instead of copying from it - by having `getData()` with the signature `static Data getData(DataFrom&& data2)`. Read more about moving here:

[What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

In my example, this would mean you would now use the raw buffer of `data2.a` for your `data` - without copying the contents of that buffer anywhere else. But that would mean you can no longer use `data2` afterwards, since its `a` field has been cannibalized, moved from.

**... or just be "lazy".**

Instead of a move-based approach, you might try something else. Suppose you defined something like this:

```
class Data {
protected:
    DataFrom& source_;

public:  
    int& a() { return source_.a; }
    int& b() { return source_.b; }

public:
    Data(DataFrom& source) : source_(source) { }
    Data(Data& other) : source_(other.source) { }
    // copy constructor?
    // assignment operators? 
};
```

Now `Data` is not a simple struct; it is more of a facade for a `DataFrom` (and perhaps some other fields and methods). That's a bit less convenient, but the benefit is that you now create a `Data` with merely a reference to a `DataFrom` and no copying of anything else. On *access*, you may need to dereference a pointer.

---

Other notes:

- Your `DataHandler` is defined as a class, but it looks like it serves as just a namespace. You never instantiate "data handlers". Consider reading:

  [Why and how should I use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4211827/1593077)
- My suggestions do not involve any C++17. Move semantics were introduced in C++11, and if you choose the "lazy" approach - that would work even in C++98.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this with [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you can write your code in a way that prevents any copying from taking place (or being able to take place), and if it compiles you will know that *statically* no copies will be made.

C++17 guarantees copy elision when returned from functions, which ensures no copies take place in certain circumstances. You can ensure this by changing your code so that `Data` has an `= delete`d copy-constructor, and changing `getData` to return a constructed object. If the code compiles correctly at all, you will be sure that no copy occurred (since copying would trigger a compile-error)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct DataFrom{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
};
static DataFrom dataFrom;   
struct Data{
    Data() = default;
    Data(const Data&) = delete; // No copy
    int a;
    int b;
};    
class DataHandler{
    public:
        static Data getData(const DataFrom& data2){
            // construct it during return
            return Data{data2.a, data2.b};
        }
    private:
        static void setA(Data& dest, const DataFrom& source){
            dest.a = source.a;
        }
        static void setB(Data& dest, const DataFrom& source){
            dest.b = source.b;
        }
};
int main(){
    auto data = DataHandler::getData(dataFrom); // copy of whole Data structure

    return 0;
}
```

This will compile without any extra copies -- you can see it [here on compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hnnqGn)

Comment: You will probably want to explicitly allow move semantics. Right now `Data` is non-moveable which greatly limits what you can do with it.

Comment: 1. You don't need to delete the copy ctor to get the NRVO to kick in, IIANM. 2. You're still making a copy of `a` and `b`, which OP has suggested stand for something "huge". 2. I'm not sure I approve of breaking the rule of 0 of what is essentially just a struct.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not suggesting you need to delete the copy ctor at all; I was just suggesting this could be used as a means to detect statically if a copy ever occurs. Perhaps I could have worded that better. For the second point, I interpreted OP's concern to be with unnecessary copies taking place, since clearly at least one copy is desired. For your 3rd point, I agree -- I was just quickly augmenting OP's example; this wasn't meant to be high-quality code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That is a good point as well, and I agree. As I just mentioned above, I wasn't trying to make this high-quality code, but rather a simple augmentation of OP's input as a demonstration for how this could be done.